# How can I add an attribute to an html element by id value (python flask lxml)

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, lxml

I would like to add a value attribute to multiple input elements. Currently, I am simply using a replace which works but is cumbersome. Is there a way to find an element by its ID attribute and simply add a value attribute?

```
page = render_template('template.html')
page = page.replace('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Company" name="Company" placeholder="Company name" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="The name of the company that the document is for." onblur="titleCase(this)">',
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Company" name="Company" placeholder="Company name" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="The name of the company that the document is for." onblur="titleCase(this)" value="' + company + '">')
```

Is there a way to do this without overcomplicating things?

EDIT: I found this an example in lxml.html documentation that encouraged me to do this:

```
def fillForm1(page, pDate, company, manager, cAddress, cPhone, cEmail ,sAddress):
form_page = fromstring(page)
form = form_page.forms[0]
form.fields = dict(
    pDate=pDate,
    Company=company,
    Manager=manager,
    cAddress=cAddress,
    cPhone=cPhone,
    cEmail=cEmail,
    sAddress=sAddress
    )
page = page.replace('<form method="post">', tostring(form, pretty_print=True, encoding='UTF-8', with_tail=False,))

return page
```

But I keep getting an error about passing a byte back when it should be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are using `render_template` you can simply use **[Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/)**

Jinja helps you to render your data where ever you want in the html page safely and no need to install anything since the the `render_template` method already uses it.

You need to specify a something like a placeholder in your html file and then pass a value to it as a keyword to the `render_template`

you need to put this in your HTML file

```html
<input value="{{company}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="Company" name="Company" placeholder="Company name" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="The name of the company that the document is for." onblur="titleCase(this)" >
```

> Now Jinja will search for a keyword (from what you've passed) named company and will substitute its value in place pf `{{company}}`

to pass the value to Jinja simply use this line in your python code

```py
company_value = "Some Value"
page = render_template('template.html', company=company_value)
```

Now When Jinja see `{{company}}` it will replace it with the value passed which is the value of `company_value = "Some Value"`

> Note that you can pass as much values as you want

---

Jinja has more features that help you to render your data like:

- loops
- if else statements
- and a lot more

Check this Documentation for a quick look [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/)

Comment: I have been working too long, I can't believe that I didn't see that. Thank you!